# Unpack list, pair up and calculate difference

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apache-spark

I want to calculate the time difference between in and out for each id. The data is in the format:

```
String,Long,String,List[String]
======================================
 in, time0, door1, [id1, id2, id3, id4]
out, time1, door1, [id1, id2, id3]
out, time2, door1, [id4, id5]
```

In the end it should end up with key-value pairs like:

```
{(id1, #time1-time0), (id2, #time1-time0), (id3, #time1-time0), (id4, #time2-time0), (id5, N/A)}
```

What would be a good approach for solving this problem?

EDIT: I have tried the following.

```
case class Data(direction: String, time:Long, door:String, ids:  List[String])
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(Data("in", 5, "d1", List("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4")),Data("out", 20, "d1", List("id1", "id2", "id3")), Data("out",50, "d1", List("id4", "id5"))))
data.flatMap(x => (x.ids, x))
```

Comment: I see the apache-spark tag. Are you looking for a way to do this with Spark? How much data do you have?

Comment: Me wanna see some code.... what have you tried...?

Comment: Yes, I want to do it with Spark. I don't have any data. I just want to learn Spark but the solution should work with millions of rows.

Comment: I have tried the following but I get an error:
data.flatMap(x => (x.get[List[String]]("list"), x))

Comment: Can you provide the classes you are using for `data`?  You can edit the question and put the code that you've tried and class definition in the question!

Comment: Added requested stuff

Comment: This working with millions of rows or not will mostly depend upon hardware running your Spark-cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> case class Data( direction: String, time: Long, door: String, ids: List[ String ] )
defined class Data

scala> val data = sc.parallelize( Seq( Data( "in", 5, "d1", List( "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4" ) ), Data( "out", 20, "d1", List( "id1", "id2", "id3" ) ), Data( "out",50, "d1", List( "id4", "id5" ) ) ) )
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Data] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:14

// Get an RDD entry for each ( id, data ) pair
scala> data.flatMap( x => x.ids.map( id => ( id, x ) ) )
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Data)] = FlatMappedRDD[1] at flatMap at <console>:17

// group by id to get data's with same id's
scala> res0.groupBy( { case ( id, data ) => id } )
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, Data)])] = ShuffledRDD[3] at groupBy at <console>:19

// convert Iterable[(String, Data)] to List[Data]
scala> res1.map( { case ( id, iter ) => ( id, iter.toList.map( { case ( i, d ) => d } ) ) } )
res2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[Data])] = MappedRDD[4] at map at <console>:21

// sort list of data's by data.time
res2.map( { case ( id, list ) => ( id, list.sortBy( d => d.time ) ) } )
res3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[Data])] = MappedRDD[5] at map at <console>:23

// get the time diff by doing lastData.time - firstData.time for each id
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

res3.map( { case ( id, list ) => {
    list match {
        case d :: Nil => ( id, None )
        case d :: tail => ( id, Some( list.last.time - d.time ) )
        case _ => ( id, None )
    }
} } )

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res6: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Option[Long])] = MappedRDD[7] at map at <console>:25
```

Now, `res6` has your desired data.

Also... I was not sure how do you wanted to use `direction` so I did not use it, modify some of the code to get what you want ( I think just the last `res3` thing need to change a little ) or you can explain it here, and may be I will give you the answer. If you have any other doubts... ask away.

It can also be achieved in a more concise way... but that will be hard to understand. That's why I have provided a verbose and simpler code.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I will try to fully understand this. The idea with direction was that out time should be subtracted with the corresponding in time.